# How can we send the OAuth authentication token in request body instead of header?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-data

I am using `spring 4.0` and `java 8.0`

I have configured my application to use `OAuth authentication`.

Presently there are **three URL's** for authentications and authorization as shown below. But I feel sending the tokens in the URL Query param or header is not smart enough, as it increases the vulnerability of the security being compromised.

**for 'grant_type=password'**

http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=kalynpradhan@gmail.com&password=abc

**for 'grant_type=refresh_token'**

http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/oauth/token?client_id=my-trusted-client&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=11918d5a-3208-403d-b699-0c60a84e8212

**And finally to access the secured resource I have**

http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/user/?access_token=188e4ed1-0ed9-44b9-ab88-e4ae2cd0895a

My Question : is there any configuration in spring (JAVA Configuration preferred) which will direct my spring application to accept the tokens in request body instead of request header or query param.

Below are my configuration files for reference:

**AuthorizationServer**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM = "MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    /*
     * The token store is the store where all the tokens are stored, It can be
     * InMemory, JDBC, etc.
     */
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /**
     * SpringData JPA dataSource injected.
     */
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * Autowiring the {@link CustomUserDetailsService} for configuring the
     * {@link UserDetailsService} which provides the required user details to
     * the security context.
     * 
     * This extra implementation of the userDetailsService is necessary because
     * after OAuth 2.0 version - 2.0.10.RELEASE the UserDetails service is not
     * automatically extracted from the context.
     * 
     * Here is a link to the documentation in the gitHub community. <a href=
     * "https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/issues/19">
     * Documentation</a>
     */
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);/*.withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT").scopes("read", "write", "trust").secret("secret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).// Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);// Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
        //@Formatter:on
*/  }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM + "/client");
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customAuthenticationProvider")
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    /**
     * Defines custom authentication provider.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();

    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/students/**");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    /**
     * This Approval store is used to direct the OAuth server to use the
     * tokenStore that is exposed as a spring bean and uses the database to
     * store all the tokens.
     * 
     * @param tokenStore
     * @return The Approval store which uses the tokenStore injected into the
     *         spring context as a bean.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
/**
 * The modified {@link UserDetailsService} implementation for providing the
 * current authorized user to the spring context along with the roles he/she
 * possesses.
 * 
 * @author KalyanaP
 *
 */
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserComponent userComponent;

    @Override   
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userComponent.getUser(email);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getRole()));
        return new AuthUser(user);
    }
}
```

Is there a more secured way of providing the `OAuth` authentication using `spring`?

Comment: "But I feel sending the tokens in the [...] header is not smart enough, as it increases the vulnerability of the security being compromised." Your feelings are incorrect. There are good reasons that using the header is the standard practice, and your attempt to put authentication in a different place from where all standard tools expect it will be counterproductive at best.

Comment: @chrylis Okay, can you please describe in detail. Because anyone with the url which contains my token can access the secured resources. I have also planned to implement CSRF token filter chain, but please explain, if using the header is a good practice or not?

Comment: How can they do that without the header? The header isn't in the URL. That's a lot of the point.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but the point is OAuth using spring security accepts the access tokens from query string and not the headers, and query string is visible in header. So I was trying for an alternative. Even if you can help me in getting one config for accepting headers that would be great.

Comment: Just don't send the token in a header, and you'll be fine. The header is not visible anywhere.

Comment: "OAuth using spring security accepts the access tokens from query string and not the headers" - Did you tried send it in the header?

Comment: @sura2k yes I tried sending it in headers, but it didn't work

Comment: It should work. You have to send it as a Bearer token. And also Spring supports JWT as well. Try this example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr

Comment: @surak2k Thanks I will try it, thanks for the info

Comment: @surak2k Thanks for the information the above project you shared helped me learn deeper about the spring security OAuth 2.0